# Compactness and sequential compactness

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a nonempty set. If the cocountable topology $\tau$ is considered on $X$, then I want to find all compact and sequential compact subsets of $X$.

Definitely only finite subsets of $X$ are compact. But I am in confusion to find all sequentially compact sets. Is there any infinite set which is sequentially compact? Plese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, the only sequentially compact sets are finite. In fact, you can show that the only convergent sequences are those that are eventually constant :

If $(x_n) \subset X$ such that $x_n \to l$, then set $A = \{x_n : x_n \neq l\}$, then $A$ is countable, and $U = X\setminus A$ is an open neighbourhood of $l$. So $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n\geq N$. But that implies that $x_n \notin A$, which means $x_n = l$ for all $n\geq N$

Now, let $Y \subset X$ be an infinite set, so choose a sequence $(x_n) \subset Y$ with distinct terms. Every possible subsequence of $(x_n)$ has distinct terms, and so does not converge. So, $Y$ is not sequentially compact.