# Regarding the question of compactness

Tags: general-topology

My question is regarding [Compactness and sequential compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533336/compactness-and-sequential-compactness)

How to show that the only compact subsets of $X$ are finite sets?

In case of specific sets like $\mathbb{N}$, we can choose cover containing open sets of the form $\mathbb N\setminus \{np: p$ is prime$, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then no finite subcollection of it will cover $\mathbb N$.

But how to start the proof in case of arbitrary sets like $X$?

Comment: The question is meaningless until you specify the topology on $X$. On any infinite set there are compact topologies.

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: the topology is cocountable as mentioned in the link

Comment: That’s what I thought initially, but then your example suggested otherwise, because it’s unnecessarily complicated. $\Bbb N$ with the co-countable topology is discrete, so you could have used the much simpler open sets $\{n\}$.

Comment: @user100943 : you should state the question instead of expecting everyone to click on the link.  Call me lazy, but you'll probably get more and better answers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ has the co-countable topology, and let $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Since $A$ is infinite, it has a countably infinite subset $A_0=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Let $A_1=A\setminus A_0$, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\{a_n\}\cup(X\setminus A_0)$; $X\setminus U_n=A_0\setminus\{a_n\}$, which is countable, so $U_n$ is open. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. If $x\in A_1$, then $x\in U_0$, and if $x\in A_0$, then $x=a_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, so $x\in U_n$. Thus, $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $A$. However, if $n\in\Bbb N$, the only member of $\mathscr{U}$ that contains $a_n$ is $U_n$, so no finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$. In fact, no proper subset of $\mathscr{U}$, finite or infinite, covers $A$: if you remove $U_n$ from $\mathscr{U}$, the remaining sets do not cover the point $a_n$.

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: I think $U_0$ should be replaced by $U_n$.

Comment: @user100943: You mean in the statement that $x\in U_0$ if $x\in A_1$? There’s no reason to do so. It happens to be true that in that case $x\in U_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, but we don’t care: we just need to be sure that $x$ is in at least one member of $\mathscr{U}$, and $U_0$ does as well as any.

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: That means $0\in \mathbb N$. But why $X\setminus U_n=A_0\setminus \{a_n\}$? Isn't $(X\setminus U_n)\cap A=A_0\setminus \{a_n\}$?

Comment: @user100943: Yes, I follow the convention that $\Bbb N$ includes $0$. The other is a mistake: I forget that I was working in $X$ rather than in $A$ with its relative topology. I’ve fixed it now.

Comment: @B.M.: OK. Thanks!

Comment: @user100943: You’re welcome! I’m glad that you caught the oversight.