# Compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent in metric space but not always in others

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

There are many discussions about such question; however, they are proof-type answer

1. [Compactness and sequential compactness in metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822236/compactness-and-sequential-compactness-in-metric-spaces)
2. [If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then I want to show that limit point compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733103/if-x-d-is-a-metric-space-then-i-want-to-show-that-limit-point-compactness-an)
3. [Compactness and sequential compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533336/compactness-and-sequential-compactness)

Could anyone use a simpler description to guide me that when both of them are equivalent and when they are not?

Comment: I don't understand: are you asking for a simplified proof of [this theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Compact) or are you looking for a classification of topological spaces which either are compact both topologically and sequentially or neither topologically nor sequentially compact?

Comment: I want a classification.